# Doctor Who episode featuring the Doctor destroying a Weeping Angel with his sonic screwdriver

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

There's a clear picture in my mind: there's this TARDIS door from inside. A Weeping Angel on the door. The Doctor (don't know which Doctor) points a sonic screwdriver at the Weeping Angel and the Weeping Angel explodes.

I know an exploding Weeping Angel sounds silly, but my memory can't deceive me like that. If something is my creation, I know that.

I have already skimmed through the list of all episodes of new *Doctor Who* (2005), but without any luck remembering that scene. Although I haven't watched old *Doctor Who*, it's a possibility that I watched that scene from old *Doctor Who*.

Which *Doctor Who* episode featured the Doctor destroying a Weeping Angel with his sonic screwdriver? And, what was the plot? How was the Doctor able to do that? Was that a ganger of a Weeping Angel?

Comment: Well it wasn't Old Who, unless you're misremembering the monster; Weeping Angels weren't introduced until 2007

Comment: @JasonBaker Don't Blink?

Comment: I can't even count how many times I've absolutely KNOWN my memory was dead-on... only to find out it wasn't. Declaring that your memory is perfect is the fastest way to find out that it's not. :-P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're describing the Doctor Who minisode "[Good As Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_as_Gold_%28Doctor_Who%29)", written by the children of Ashdene School to celebrate the upcoming London 2012 Olympics:

Comment: Oh, it was special episode. BTW, how was he able to do that?

Comment: From what I can tell, he used the screwdriver to cause all the positivity and goodwill generated by the Olympic spirit to flow into the Angel, causing it to explode. And yes, I'm aware how dumb that sounds. That's because it was written by children.

Comment: Sometimes people tend to forget that Dr. Who originated as, and is still filmed today as a children's show.

Comment: @Jenayah - But of course. And a [spare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5ZFx4GZ5bw)

Comment: *And yes, I'm aware how dumb that sounds. That's because it was written by children* - well... given some episodes of late... I'd rather children be having a go at scripting an episode again :)

Comment: @JonClements - This minisode was more entertaining than the entire latest series.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it was a 2012 episode "Good as Gold."

Comment: Ahem...(see below)

Comment: Or above? LOL Oops. When I first clicked on it it says 0 answers...stupid slow work internet.

Comment: Yah, don't worry about it ... @Richard does that all the time. He never asks, just posts up the answer. The correct one, I might add. My goodness, what is this world coming to.